# Bash - Getting count of a word group by every second

Tags: bash, shell, group-by, count, centos7

Here is sample of text file. I need to count by the word "Id" group by every seconds from the string before the pipleline("|")

```
2019-02-10 12:00:03.448|Id: 26102338
2019-02-10 12:00:03.448|Id: 25941418
2019-02-10 12:00:03.449|Id: 25827373
2019-02-10 12:00:03.449|Id: 26102038
2019-02-10 12:00:03.449|Id: 25929358

2019-02-10 12:00:04.382 | =====================================Start 
fetching=====================================
2019-02-10 12:00:04.451 |
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 25713118
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26076208
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26079643
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26085973
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26090023
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26130133
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 25954018
2019-02-10 12:00:04.427|Id: 25951468
2019-02-10 12:00:04.427|Id: 26136148
2019-02-10 12:00:04.427|Id: 26103013
2019-02-10 12:00:04.427|Id: 25806433
```

I need to make the output like this:

```
Time               |Count(Id)  
2019-02-10 12:00:03|5    
2019-02-10 12:00:04|11
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If every line always has an `Id` on the end, and you don't mind the format being the other way round this is quite simple:

```
grep 'Id:' /tmp/data.txt | cut -f 1 -d '.' | uniq -c

   5 2019-02-10 12:00:03   
  11 2019-02-10 12:00:04
```

1. `grep` throws away blank lines.
2. `cut` picks the field before the dot (i.e the time without ms).
3. `uniq` counts the total number each time appears.

(If the file isn't always in order, you may also need a `sort` in there before the `uniq`).

To reverse the data and add a pipe to match your requested format, you can pipe the output through sed - something like:

```
sed -re 's/ +([0-9]+) (.+)/\2|\1/'
```

Comment: To clarify: This would count the number of lines in the lfile for each timestamp (precision to the second). While this makes sense when looking at the input data, it is not what the OP asked, because (for instance) it is irrelevant whether the string `Id:` does or does not apply in the line. To be honest, I don't really understand the requirements of the OP here, so I can't offer a better solution....

Comment: I have updated my question. The file would contain such data. Can you please update your answer according to my question.

Comment: I've changed the `grep` to begin by only picking out lines with `Id:` in them.

Comment: thanks a lot. It's working @match

Comment: What if I want the count later  and a pipeline between those values. like
`2019-02-10 12:00:03|6`

Comment: Have added some `sed` to format your output.

Answer (score -1):

data.txt

```
2019-02-10 12:00:03.448|Id: 26102338
2019-02-10 12:00:03.448|Id: 25941418
2019-02-10 12:00:03.449|Id: 25827373
2019-02-10 12:00:03.449|Id: 26102038
2019-02-10 12:00:03.449|Id: 25929358

2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 25713118
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26076208
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26079643
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26085973
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26090023
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 26130133
2019-02-10 12:00:04.426|Id: 25954018
2019-02-10 12:00:04.427|Id: 25951468
2019-02-10 12:00:04.427|Id: 26136148
2019-02-10 12:00:04.427|Id: 26103013
2019-02-10 12:00:04.427|Id: 25806433

2019-02-10 12:00:03.427|Id: 25806433
```

command:

```
grep 'Id:' data.txt | cut -f 1 -d '.' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2" "$3" | "$1}'
```

> sort before counting to avoid disordered timestamps

output:

```
2019-02-10 12:00:03 | 6
2019-02-10 12:00:04 | 11
```

Comment: Can i show the count later and pipeline between those values like the exact output I want?

Comment: Yes , you can.Check answer.I updated it.

Comment: If you are using Awk anyway, you want to do all the rest of the processing in Awk, too.

Comment: why is that?...are you saving cpu power more there..i don't think so? @tripleee